# React button not firing onTouchEnd

Tags: ios, reactjs

I am using React button with child components that change based on the state like, is button pressed, touched etc. I have defined custom event handlers that change the states, isPressed, isTouched etc.

**Issue:** On iPhone , the onTouchEnd is not firing. With, iOS voiceover turned ON the issue is more prominent because mouse events are not fired. So the user has to tap-tap twice to actually click succeed.

Here are the events -->

```
const onMouseDown = function(){
    setPressed(true);
  };
  const onMouseUp = function(){
    handleClick();
  }
  const onTouchStart = function(){
      setTouched(true);
      setHover(false);
      setPressed(true);
  };
  const onKeyDown = function(keyboardEvent: any){
    if (keyboardEvent.key === "Enter") {
      handleClick();
    };
  };
  const onTouchMove = function(e: any){
    e.preventDefault();
  };
  const onTouchEnd = function(e: any) {
      e.preventDefault();
      setTouched(false);
      setHover(false);
      if (!clicked) {
        handleClick();
      }
  };
  const onFocus = function () {
      if (!touched) {
        setHover(true);

      }
  };
  const onKeyUp = function(keyboardEvent: any) {
    if (keyboardEvent.key === "Enter") {
      handleClick();
    }
  };
  const onBlur = function() {
      setHover(false);
      setPressed(false);
  };
  const onMouseOver = function () {
      if (!touched) {
        setHover(true);
      }
  };
  const onMouseOut = function () {
        setHover(false);
        setPressed(false);
  }
```

This is the button content -

```
<button
  style={buttonStyle}
  onMouseDown={onMouseDownf}
  onMouseUp={onMouseUp}
  onKeyDown={onKeyDown}
  onKeyUp={onKeyUp}
  onMouseOver={onMouseOver}
  onFocus={onFocus}
  onMouseOut={onMouseOut}
  onBlur={onBlur}
  onTouchStart={onTouchStart}
  onTouchCancel={onTouchCancel}
  onTouchMove={onTouchMove}
  onTouchEnd={onTouchEnd}
  onClick={() => { console.log("onClick") }}
  disabled={props.disabled}
   >
     {
       pressed ? <Spinner styles={newSpinnerStyle} size={SpinnerSize.large} /> : normalButtonContent
     }
  </button>
</>
```

If I remove the dynamic content it works fine, i.e. -->

```
{ pressed ? <Spinner styles={newSpinnerStyle} size={SpinnerSize.large} /> : normalButtonContent }
```

to

```
{ normalButtonContent }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like when the child component changes, the button (i.e. the parent) is re-rendered. And so the onTouchEnd is not fired. Probably a race condition between the re-render and onTouchEnd call.

Moving the dynamic component i.e. spinner / normalButtonContent outside of the button helped workaround this issue.